# Help about vector

Tags: linear-algebra

I am trying to understand a solution in which $\vec{R}$ ,in ${k\vec{R} + \vec{R} \times \vec{A} = \vec{B}}$, is expressed as ${\vec{R} = a\vec{A} + b\vec{B} + c( \vec{A}\times\vec{B})}$.Here ${k,a,b,c}$ are scalars and ${\vec{A}}$ & ${\vec{B}}$ are non-collinear. I want to know the theory/reason behind why ${\vec{R}}$ is expressed this way.

Thank you! :))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the use of the vector product, you are obviously working in a 3 dimensional space. Therefore if $\vec{A}$ and $\vec{B}$ are non-collinear, $(\vec{A},\vec{B},\vec{A}\times\vec{B})$ is necessarily a basis and any other vector $\vec{R}$ have a unique decomposition $\vec{R} =a\vec{A}+b\vec{B} +c\vec{A}\times\vec{B}$ in such a basis.

This fact is completely independent of any additional constraints on $\vec{R}$ such as $k\vec{R}+ \vec{R}\times\vec{A} =\vec{B}$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Can you please provide me link to some notes on this topic so that i can read about it further. My books don't have any proofs regarding the above. Thank you! :))

Comment: @AbirMukherjee Any book on linear algebra will do. You will learn about linear vector spaces such as $\mathbb{R}^3$ where important ideas such as linear independence of vectors, basis etc. will be discussed.

Answer (score 1):

If $\vec{A}\in\mathbb{R}^3$ and $\vec{B}\in\mathbb{R}^3$ are non-collinear, then these two vectors and  $\vec{A}\times \vec{B}\neq 0$ provide a basis for any vector in $\mathbb{R}^3$. Hence, given $\vec{R}\in\mathbb{R}^3$, you can write it as a linear combination of the three basis vectors.